# Can I connect a Pixel 2 XL to a monitor with USB-C input?

Tags: external-display, google-pixel-2, usb-c

I have a Pixel 2 XL and am looking for an external monitor. If I buy a monitor that has a USB-C input and I connect the phone using a USB-C to USB-C cable, will the screen be displayed to the external monitor?

Comment: Please read https://www.reddit.com/r/GooglePixel/comments/8f0yas/is_there_any_way_to_output_video_from_the_pixel_2/

Comment: That thread doesn't talk about USB-C to USB-C connections. It talks about display link.

Comment: The question is about "ANY way to output video from the Pixel 2 XL". If a simple USB-C DisplayPort/HDMI alternative output would exist I assume someone would have mentioned it.